# Quicksort out of bounds or loop

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm currently trying to implement quicksort in java, when i run the programm i either get an index out of bounds for the array length or an infinite loop, dont ask me how. Furthermore the swapping itself, when it works, is not correct so yea.

```
public class Quicksort {

   /*
    * Entry method for Quicksort
    */
   public static void quicksort(int[] a) {
      quicksort(a, 0, a.length-1);
   }

   /*
    * Quicksort! 
    * Operates in-place, i.e. it doesn't create a copy.
    */  
   public static void quicksort(int[] a, int from, int to) {
      // Base case: Sorting range is 1 element or empty.
      if(from >= to){
         return;
      }
      // TODO
      else{
         
         
         
         int ipivot = from; // Pivot p
         System.out.println("Pivot p = " + a[ipivot]);
         printArray(a);
         
         // Split the array in two ranges: Left are the elements <=p and right >p.
         // Do this by swapping the elements that don't belong in the given range. 
         // If i and j cross, swapping is finished.
         int i = ipivot+1;
         int j = to;
         while (i<j) {
            // Look for an element <=p right-hand side 
            while(j>= 0 &&a[j]>a[ipivot]){
               j--;
            }
            
            
            // Look for an element >p left-hand side 
            while(i< a.length && a[i]<a[ipivot]){
               i++;
            }
            
            
            // Swap the elements, but only if pointers aren't crossed.
            if (i<j) {
               swap(a, i, j);
            } 
            else {
               break;
            }
 
               
         }
         // The pivot can now be moved to its final position at i.
         // NOTE: Check if pivot needs to be moved BEFORE i.
         int ipivot_final =i;
         System.out.println("swapping " + a[ipivot] +" @"+ipivot+" and " + a[ipivot_final]+" @"+ipivot_final + " (pivot)");
         swap(a, ipivot, ipivot_final);
         
         printArray(a);
         System.out.println();
         
         // Recursion case: Sort left and right range of pivot recursively.
         quicksort(a, from, ipivot_final-1);
         quicksort(a, ipivot_final+1, to);
      }
   }
   /*
    * HELPER METHODS
    */
   public static void printArray(int[] a) {
      for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

   public static boolean isSorted( int[] array ) {
      for ( int j=0; j<array.length-1; j++ ) {
         if (array[j] > array[j+1])
            return false;      
      }
      return true;
   }

   private static int[] createRandomArray(int size, int minVal, int maxVal) {
      int[] a = new int[size];
      for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
         a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal) + minVal);
      }
      return a;
   }

   private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
      int tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
   }
   
   
   /*
    * MAIN
    */

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int MINSIZE = 10;
      final int MAXSIZE = 10;
      for (int size = MINSIZE; size <= MAXSIZE; size++) {
         int[] a = createRandomArray(size, 0, size);
         System.out.println("Unsorted array of size "+a.length);
         printArray(a);
         System.out.println("\nRunning Quicksort ...");
         quicksort(a);
         System.out.println("\nSorted array:");
         printArray(a);
         assert isSorted(a) : "Array is not sorted!";
         if (isSorted(a))
            System.out.println("\n\nSuccess!!\n\n");
         else
            System.out.println("\n\nERROR !! Something went wrong.\n\n");
      }
   }

}
```

I've tried changing the order of the conditions aswell as the conditions themself

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions in these loops are wrong:

> ```
>             while(j>= 0 &&a[j]>a[ipivot]){
>                j--;
>             }
>             
>             
>             // Look for an element >p left-hand side 
>             while(i< a.length && a[i]<a[ipivot]){
>                i++;
>             }
> ```

`j` should not be allowed to go below `from`, and `i` should not be allowed to go above `to`.  Alternatively, you could just break the loops as soon as `i` and `j` cross:

```
            while (j >= i && a[j] > a[ipivot]) {
               j--;
            }
            
            
            // Look for an element >p left-hand side 
            while (i <= j && a[i] < a[ipivot]) {
               i++;
            }
```

This comment is incorrect:

> ```
>          // The pivot can now be moved to its final position at i.
> ```

The final position for the pivot is not `i`, but rather `i-1`.  Which can also be spelled `j` because the loop will terminate as soon as `i` and `j` cross.

One way to see that is to consider the extreme case that the pivot element happens to be the least in the subarray.  Then `i` will never be incremented from its initial value of `ipivot + 1`, but the correct index for the pivot element is its initial one, `ipivot`.

Note also that if you allow `i` to increase all the way to `a.length` then at that point evaluating `a[i]` will yield that `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  This too is related to the fact that at the end of the partitioning loop, the top index of the left partition is `i - 1`, not `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation, using an algorithm from the *Wikipedia* article.
*[Wikipedia – Quicksort – Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)*.

The comments are from the original.

```java
// Sorts a (portion of an) array, divides it into partitions, then sorts those
void quicksort(int[] A, int lo, int hi) {
    // Ensure indices are in correct order
    if (lo >= hi || lo < 0) return;

    // Partition array and get the pivot index
    int p = partition(A, lo, hi);

    // Sort the two partitions
    quicksort(A, lo, p - 1); // Left side of pivot
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi); // Right side of pivot
}

// Divides array into two partitions
int partition(int[] A, int lo, int hi) {
    int pivot = A[hi]; // Choose the last element as the pivot

    // Temporary pivot index
    int i = lo - 1, t;

    for (int j = lo; j <= hi - 1; j++) {
        // If the current element is less than or equal to the pivot
        if (A[j] <= pivot) {
            // Move the temporary pivot index forward
            i = i + 1;
            // Swap the current element with the element at the temporary pivot index
            t = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = t;
        }
    }

    // Move the pivot element to the correct pivot position (between the smaller and larger elements)
    i = i + 1;
    t = A[i];
    A[i] = A[hi];
    A[hi] = t;
    return i; // the pivot index
}
```